# HTML code Inspection of blocks split up into several files in PhpStorm

Tags: php, html, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to tell PhpStorm to only evaluate header.php together with footer.php (as a browser would do when running index.php)?

Consider a project containing 4 files

- index.php    -   server side stuff, business logic
- header.php -   html with some php prints
- item.php      -   html with some php prints
- footer.php   -   html with some php prints

index.php

```
<?php
//Do some important stuff
include 'templates/header.php';

foreach($some_array as $item){
    include 'templates/item.php';
}

include 'templates/footer.php';
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title><?=$foo;?></title></head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
```

item.php

```
        <div class="item"><?=$var;?></div>
```

footer.php

```
    </div> <!-- close #main -->
</body>
</html>
```

When I do "Inspect Code..." on a project like this I get errors/warnings of the type "Closing tag matches nothing (at line x)" and similar. Is there a way to tell PhpStorm to only evaluate header.php together with footer.php? I Know that you can opt out "header.php" and "footer.php" from the scope but I would like to evaluate them as a unit.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no real solution currently, this is the corresponding ticket:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32239

I managed to remove the warning by simply putting the closing tags into PHP echo statements, e.g. `<?php echo "</div></div>"; ?>` instead of `</div></div>`, which stops PHPStorm from analyzing the HTML.