# Is there a way to get PhpStorm to look for closing HTML tags within included files?

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

is there a way to use the HTML auto tag closing feature of PhpStorm ( v 8.0.1 ) mixed with a PHP include?

Like:

---

fileone.php:

```
<div>
 <p>
 Lore Ipsum
 </p>
<?php include_once( 'filetwo.php' ); ?>
```

---

filetwo.php:

```
<?php
echo 'Lore Ipsum';
?>
**</div>**
```

---

So that PhpStorm checks wether open HTML Tags are closed in an included file?

I would appreciate any info!

JayWee

Comment: This is a bad habit. You better learn to close tags in same file.

Comment: Nope. Either ignore those warnings or redo your HTML to save opening and closing tags in the same file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508423/html-code-inspection-of-templates-in-phpstorm

Comment: @Marek Well sometimes in Wordpress Developement you have the tags split up in e.g header.php and footer.php where you want to let a DIV surround all of the content 'between' them.